# How can I identify whether the NetworkInterface object is of a physical NIC

Tags: java, network-interface

How can I identify whether the `NetworkInterface` object is of a physical NIC and not a software/emulation of NIC.

I know there are methods like `NetworkInterface#isVirtual` and `NetworkInterface#getParent` which, theoretically, tells whether or not this is a physical interface.

But clearly this is not giving me right answer because I get below o/p when I use these methods, and `127.0.0.1` is a loop back software interface.

Am I missing something?

**Code:**

```
 Enumeration<NetworkInterface> nets = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
    for (NetworkInterface netIf : Collections.list(nets)) {
        System.out.printf("Display name: %s\n", netIf.getDisplayName());
        System.out.printf("Name: %s\n", netIf.getName());
        System.out.printf("Up? %s\n", netIf.isUp());
        System.out.printf("Loopback? %s\n", netIf.isLoopback());
        System.out.printf("PointToPoint? %s\n", netIf.isPointToPoint());
        System.out.printf("Supports multicast? %s\n", netIf.supportsMulticast());
        System.out.printf("Virtual? %s\n", netIf.isVirtual());
        System.out.printf("Hardware address: %s\n", Arrays.toString(netIf.getHardwareAddress()));
        System.out.printf("MTU: %s\n", netIf.getMTU());
        System.out.printf("Parent: %s\n", netIf.getParent());
        System.out.println("InetAddress:");
        Enumeration<InetAddress> inetAddresses  = netIf.getInetAddresses();
        int count = 1;
        for(InetAddress inetAddress : Collections.list(inetAddresses)){
            System.out.println("\tInetAddress #" + count);
            printInetAddressInfo(inetAddress, "\t\t");
            count++;
        }
        System.out.println("SubInterfaces:");
        displaySubInterfaces(netIf);
        netIf = null;
        System.out.printf("\n");
    }
```

**Results:**

```
Display name: Software Loopback Interface 1
Name: lo
Up? true
Loopback? true
PointToPoint? false
Supports multicast? true
Virtual? false
Hardware address: null
MTU: -1
Parent: null
InetAddress:
    InetAddress #1
        inetAddress: /127.0.0.1
    InetAddress #2
        inetAddress: /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
SubInterfaces:
```

Comment: Did you ever get any further information on this problem? I too would like to find out whether a network adapter is a real physical one or not.

Comment: `netIf.getHardwareAddress() != null` can get rid of a large part of unwanted interfaces, but not all of them.

Answer (score 1):

> Am I missing something?

I think the problem is that you are interpreting `isVirtual` incorrectly.  The javadoc says:

> `public boolean isVirtual()`
>
> Returns whether this interface is a virtual interface (also called *subinterface*). Virtual interfaces are, on some systems, interfaces created as a child of a physical interface and given different settings (like address or MTU). Usually the name of the interface will the name of the parent followed by a colon (:) and a number identifying the child since there can be several virtual interfaces attached to a single physical interface.

As you can see, the javadoc is using "virtual interface" to mean the same thing as "subinterface"; i.e. a second IP address associated with a NIC.  This is not the same as *any* non-physical interface.

The `127.0.0.1` is actually the primary IP address of the software loopback device.  That is clearly a non-physical device, but it is not a subinterface for some other primary interface, either physical or virtual.

This is a bit confusing, but then the word "virtual" is rubbery in lots of IT-related contexts.

For the record, this "subinterface == virtual interface" nomenclature is not standard either.  Cisco use "virtual interface" to mean *"Loopback interfaces, Null interfaces, Subinterfaces or Tunnel interfaces"*; e.g. http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/12_4/interface/configuration/guide/inb_virt.html#wp1027188

Comment: Thanks for the detailed information. So, is there any API using which I can identify whether given interface is physical NIC or not?

Comment: AFAIK, no.  Though you could use `isLoopback()` and `isVirtual()` together.  (One issue here is that the OS itself might not know whether the NIC is truly physical; e.g. on a virtualized platform.)  But why do you need to know if the NIC is "physical" .... whatever that means?

Comment: I have a test env. server (Linux box), it can be reached using 2 FQDN's - let's say `abc-sit.xyz.ca` and `abc-sit2.xyz.ca`, I wanted to understand whether that system has 2 NIC's or just one, while other one is simply a software interface.